# CSS color property doesn't work when used along side with pointer-events property in Safari OSX and iOS, whenever DOM gets updated

Tags: javascript, css, ios, macos, safari

I have this problem where css color property doesn't work when used along side with pointer-events property in Safari OSX and iOS, whenever DOM gets updated.

Consider these simple codes below:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
Click Me!
</div>

<div class="ux-capacity-variant   v-normal-bottom v-normal-right  disabled" >
    <div class="show-for-medium-up section-header  text-center capacity">128GB</div> 
</div>

<div class="ux-capacity-variant   v-normal-bottom v-normal-right  " >
    <div class="show-for-medium-up section-header  text-center capacity">258GB</div> 
</div>

<div class="ux-capacity-variant   v-normal-bottom v-normal-right  " >
    <div class="show-for-medium-up section-header  text-center capacity">512GB</div> 
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.test').click(function() {
  $('.ux-capacity-variant').toggleClass('disabled');
});

});
```

CSS:

```
.ux-capacity-variant.disabled {
cursor: default;
pointer-events: none;
color: grey
}

.ux-capacity-variant{
color: red
}
```

Codepen code also available here: https://codepen.io/ardnet5/pen/ZEKLXvM

Open that in Safari OSX and iOS, also on Chrome iOS, and click "Click Me!" to demonstrate.

In Safari browser, the css color property is NOT applied correctly - when use along with pointer-events property, whenever DOM gets updated (via Javascript event).

We see the correct color in Computed css in Safari dev tools. Still the wrong color show up on the screen (it supposed to shown red color on NON .disabled class, but instead it's STILL showing grey).

Btw, this is working in Chrome, and other browsers, in other OS (ie: Win).

Is there any workaround to make css color property work? or is this genuine bug in Safari?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity does it work if you move the color property above the pointer events in the css?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I just did, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we just wasted a bit of time till we found this question, apparently, this is true we had problems with Vue.js and the DOM not being updated properly when we wanted to disable the button.

Our final solution was to add the `:disabled="$props.disabled"` to the component plus adding a class as well (you should evaluate to use proper html syntax instead of a `div` use a proper `button`), you can do that with plain JS or Jquery as well and then style it

```
  &--disabled {
    color: $color-button-disable;

    &:hover {
      background-color: unset;
      cursor: unset;
    }
  }
```

the final result it's the same and it works in all browsers.

Comment: hi Sebastiano, thanks so much for the suggestion by using the `button` html syntax instead. Appreciate it!

For now I think this is acceptable workaround. I just need to figure out how to make the changes from my side since this is might be a major changes.

cheers!

Comment: hi Sebastiano, just wanna update, looks like issue is not happening on iOS anymore, perhaps I upgraded it to v.14.7.1, can you confirm on your side? thanks!

Comment: I think in 14.7.1 we didn't have the issue but as we have a more broad market to target we had to push the fix live.

Answer (score 0):

comment out `pointer-events: none;` this line of code to verify, i have no problem with my personal test

Comment: Hi M_JSL, yes, I'm aware that if I commented out `pointer-events` it works. Unfortunately due to certain requirement I still needed that `pointer-events` property.